# Change just the font size in SWT

Tags: fonts, swt

I need to use a larger font for one of the labels.

```
label.setFont( new Font(display,"Arial", 14, SWT.BOLD ) );
```

but obviously Arial is not always the default font. I want to change just the size and keep everything else at default values.

Can I do something like

```
label.setFontSize( 14 );
```

to avoid setting the other parameters? Or can I at least find out the name of the font that is actually being used as default?

Comment: Be careful using Font in this way, it needs to be disposed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I believe you could do something like

```
FontData[] fD = label.getFont().getFontData();
fD[0].setHeight(16);
label.setFont( new Font(display,fD[0]));
```

As long as no more than one font is returned, that should work.

Comment: Be sure to dispose the new Font afterwards! See https://www.eclipse.org/articles/swt-design-2/swt-design-2.html

Answer (score 34):

You can do the following:

```
FontData[] fontData = label.getFont().getFontData();
for(int i = 0; i < fontData.length; ++i)
    fontData[i].setHeight(14);

final Font newFont = new Font(display, fontData);
label.setFont(newFont);

// Since you created the font, you must dispose it
label.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
    public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
        newFont.dispose();
    }
});
```

Comment: dispose(image) makes no sense and is probably an copy and paste error