# How can I safely change listeners?

Tags: java, swt

I have an application where I need to change font sizes frequently.  A question posted a year ago on this forum ([Change just the font size in SWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449968/change-just-the-font-size-in-swt)) gave me some of the information I needed, but I've still got some unknowns I haven't figured out yet.

In particular, someone signing as [hudsonb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53923/hudsonb) offered a helpful code fragment which I'd like to reproduce below:

```
FontData[] fontData = label.getFont().getFontData();
for(int i = 0; i < fontData.length; ++i)
    fontData[i].setHeight(14);

final Font newFont = new Font(display, fontData);
label.setFont(newFont);

// Since you created the font, you must dispose it
label.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
    public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
        newFont.dispose(image);
    }
});
```

Suppose I used code like this to change font sizes frequently.  Aren't I creating a whole sequence of DisposeListeners, and adding them to the label's listener queue?  Don't I need to remove the previous listener each time before adding a new listener?  Or is there some mechanism I don't understand that makes this unnecessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative would be to add a `DisposeListener` that maintains a list of Fonts it needs to dispose of when finished with, e.g.

```
class FontDisposer implements DisposeListener {
    private List<Font> toDispose;

    public FontDisposer() {
        toDispose = new ArrayList<Font>();
    }

    @Override
    public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
            // Dispose all fonts in toDispose
    }

    public void registerFont(Font f) {
        toDispose.add(f);
    }
}

class UIWotsit extends SomeUIClass {
    private FontDisposer disposer;

    public UIWotsit() {
        disposer = new FontDisposer();
        addDisposeListener(disposer);
    }

    public void changeFont(Font f) {
        disposer.registerFont(f);
        // Do all the font changing stuff
    }
}
```

This may not suit your particular application but having something that maintains a list of Fonts is probably a reasonable start. You could also use an anonymous DisposeListener that calls a method in whatever code manages the Font creation/changing/disposal:

```
class OtherFontDisposer implements DisposeListener {
    @Override
    public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
        myCleverFontManager.disposeOfAll();
    }
}
```

It all depends on whether you are creating new labels or not, and whether you want to dispose of Fonts immediately or only when the UI is disposed of.

Comment: Ah, this is very clever.  Much less work than what I was thinking of.

Comment: Nice. Why bother initializing `toDispose` in the constructor thought, instead of `private List<Font> toDispose = new ArrayList<Font>();`?

Comment: That's just my personal preference. It makes no difference functionally, but I find the code easier to read that way. Both are fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should remove the old listeners. Do this with:

```
private DisposeListener listener = null;
//...
if (listener != null)
    label.removeDisposeListener(listener);
listener = new DisposeListener() {
    public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
        newFont.dispose(image);
    }
}
label.addDisposeListener(listener);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was wondering if I needed to do.  Since the new listener is created at a distant place and time in the code, to do this I would need to preserve a handle to the previous listener such that it can be available at the disposal point.  I can do that, but it's a lot of work, and I'm trying to find out if it's necessary.  Your vote is: probably yes?

Comment: Yeah. I was trying to think of a better way around it, but this seems like the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your font size often, you'll probably also change back to sizes, that you've already used. So you might want to cache your `Font` instances. To do so, you can use the `FontRegistry` from JFace ([JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/resource/FontRegistry.html)) instead of a list. You won't need to dispose the `Fonts`, as this is done by the registry when your `Display` is disposed.

You still have to put your `FontData` into the registry if it doesn't contain the size you need yet.

Comment: Cool -- I didn't know about the FontRegistry.  Thanks!